# Error accessing field [xxxx] by reflection for persistent property

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the following error when I hit an endpoint with Error , I have 2 classes where one is a Entity and the other is a view.

### It is giving error when Entity is being converted to view

```
Error accessing field [private long com.ge.power.brs.domains.PartOperation.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.ge.power.brs.domains.PartOperation#id] : PartOperationView{id=2969, operationOrder=1, name='Rec & ID', code='0011', status=PENDING, comment='', operationId=2', partTagNo=0', skippedOperations=null', formData=null}; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private long com.ge.power.brs.domains.PartOperation.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.ge.power.brs.domains.PartOperation#id] : PartOperationView{id=2969, operationOrder=1, name='Rec & ID', code='0011', status=PENDING, comment='', operationId=2', partTagNo=0', skippedOperations=null', formData=null}
```

---

I have the 2 classes :

```
@Table(name = "part_operations", schema = "brs")
@Entity
public class PartOperation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "part_id")
    private long partId;

    @Column(name = "operation_id")
    private long operationId;
```

---

```
public class PartOperationView {

    private long id;

    private long operationOrder;

    private String name;

    private String code;

    private OperationStatus status;

    private String comment;

    private String operationId;

    private long partTagNo;

    private Map<String, Object> formData;

    private List<PartOperationView> skippedOperations;





    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getOperationOrder() {
        return operationOrder;
    }
```

---

Error in local server:

```
2016-12-12 16:33:46.705[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m47144[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9000-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private long com.ge.power.brs.domains.PartOperation.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.ge.power.brs.domains.PartOperation#id] : PartOperationView{id=2969, operationOrder=1, name='Rec & ID', code='0011', status=PENDING, comment='', operationId=2', partTagNo=0', skippedOperations=null', formData=null}; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private long com.ge.power.brs.domains.PartOperation.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.ge.power.brs.domains.PartOperation#id] : PartOperationView{id=2969, operationOrder=1, name='Rec & ID', code='0011', status=PENDING, comment='', operationId=2', partTagNo=0', skippedOperations=null', formData=null}] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field com.ge.power.brs.domains.PartOperation.id to com.ge.power.brs.core.views.PartOperationView
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.getLong(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
```

---

Below is the converter code:

```
  @Override
    public PartOperationView convertToView(PartOperation partOperation) {
        if (partOperation == null) {
            return null;
        }

        PartOperationView partOperationView = new PartOperationView();

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(partOperation, partOperationView);
        // operation id is a required field and should always exists, so we won't check for null
        long operationId = partOperation.getOperationId();
        partOperationView.setOperationId(String.valueOf(operationId));

        if (partOperation.getFormData() != null) {
            try {
                TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() { };
                partOperationView.setFormData(objectMapper.readValue(partOperation.getFormData(), typeRef));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The form data field is not in the correct format.", e);
            }
        }

        return partOperationView;
    }
```

Comment: can you add the code when you make the conversion ?

Comment: Added the converter code

Comment: If you are using the beanUtlis fo apache commons it should be `copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)` in your code it will be  `BeanUtils.copyProperties(partOperationView, partOperation);`